# I want to run a .jar file from a ubuntu (Samba sharing)

Tags: java, jar, samba

I want to run jar file from a Ubuntu shared folder means I have placed a jar file on samba sharing and want to execute it from other Ubuntu systems. currently i have placed complied jar file in samba sharing but its not working. Is this possible to do that? Please help me

Comment: Does the user trying to run the jar have permission to read it?

Comment: Please give us the output of `ls -l` on the directory that the `jar` file resides in.

Comment: Define "not working": Is there an error message? Can the user see the file at all? Is Java working on the other Ubuntu at all?

Comment: I have given 777 permissions. If I put .jar file on system desktop(Ubuntu) then its working fine. But If I am placing same jar file in samba sharing then its not working. Even its working from same samba sharing in windows user but not working with Ubuntu users

Answer (score 0):

You need java installed at the host you execute the jar file. JAR are not executable without installed JRE.

You need to provide all dependency jar files also.

Comment: I have already installed Oracle JRE 8 on Ubuntu..Its running independently on Ubuntu but not through samba sharing.